# kendo datepicker month template with min and max value

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i have set a min and a max value on a kendo datepicker. Now the dates that are not in range are not shown, but i want to see the dates, but grayed out. 
I was looking at the monthtemplate property, but i can't get my template right. I have following code, but it gives a template error.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.PurchaseDate)
                      .Value(Model.PurchaseDate)
                      .Max(DateTime.Today)
                      .MonthTemplate("# if data.date < '"+DateTime.Today+"') { #" +
                         "<div class='inarray'>#= data.value #</div>" +
                      "# } else { #" +
                         "<div class='outofarray'>#= data.value #</div>" +
                      "# } #")       
                      .Events(ev => ev.Change("setMinExpiryDate"))

                )
```

thanks for your help

Comment: ahhhh Kendo Client Templates ahhhhhhh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it wasn't even that difficult, there is also an empty template you can set. And that did the trick for me.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.PurchaseDate)
                      .Value(Model.PurchaseDate)
                      .Max(DateTime.Today)
                      .MonthTemplate(m=>m.Empty("<div class='outofarray'>#= data.value #</div>"))
                      .Events(ev => ev.Change("setMinExpiryDate")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.PurchaseDate)
                      .Value(DateTime.Now)
                      .Max(DateTime.Today)
                      .MonthTemplate("# if (data.date < '" + DateTime.Today + "') { #" +
                         "<div class='inarray'>#= data.value #</div>" +
                      "# } else { #" +
                         "<div class='outofarray'>#= data.value #</div>" +
                      "# } #")
                      .Events(e => e.Change("setMinExpiryDate"))
```